# Javascript: How to create a rounded corner tab menu?

Tags: javascript, rounded-corners

[image]

Do you know any rounded corners tab like this one that I can download? Or how can I create a tab like that? Do the use of images in the tab menus are required or not? I used the:

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
```

but it is not perfect. Do you know any helpful links/tutorials about rounded corner tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best-looking rounded corners are always going to be those done using an image. Anything else is the browser's best attempt, which may not be what you want. It's also far easier to just use images.

You just need a small image for each corner, and another tileable set of images for the rest of the border. Plug it all into CSS classes and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Matthew. I have tried finding JS tabs with rounded corners with easy customization but I can't find one. I will just create my own images of rounded tab and my own JS tabs.

I was thinking that the tab menu's background will be an image applied with the sliding doors technique so that a very large text will be covered by the image background.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet supported by all browsers, but you can use CSS3 to easily display rounded corners without the need for images or javascript:

```
<div style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;">
    Rounded corners!
</div>
```

More info: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border

This should allow for graceful degradation in older browsers (just won't show as rounded), but I'd still be inclined to go with images if you want to ensure all your users have the same experience.

Comment: I am already using that but you can't use that to create rounded javascript tabs like in the image that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't u use jQuery UI? They have nice rounded tabs.
See http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery

Comment: jQueryUI only has rounded corners on browsers that natively support them (Mozilla Firefox and the Webkit gang)

Comment: Because jQuery UI Tabs has a conflict in Drupal's accordion of fieldset.